# Plotting pins on MKMapView from a feed

Tags: iphone, ios, nsmutablearray, mkmapview, mapkit

I'm trying to plot multiple pins coming from a feed on a mapView. The feed is being parsed in the following format into the `NSMutableArray`called ***items***:

```
{
    date = "19/02/2013";
    firstname = Tom;
    latitude = "52.45321";
    longitude = "-1.7172";
    name = "Birmingham NEC";
    surname = Thompson;
    time = "10:15";
}
```

How do I go about doing this? Also do I need to pull the longitude and latitude from ***items*** into a different array or can I used ***items*** as it is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you follow this tutorial you will learn everything you need to do .
http://www.raywenderlich.com/21365/introduction-to-mapkit-in-ios-6-tutorial

Good luck